# Preloading an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to pre-load just one image, therefor I am not using an array.

The following code never fires when debugging. I have a break set on the line.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


        $('<img/>').src = 'myimagepathhere';


 </script>
```

Do I need to put it somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: `$('<img/>').prop('src', 'myimagepathhere')`, to start.

Comment: The point is there is absolutely no reason to use jQuery for this simple task. It's no shorter or faster than `new Image().src = 'myimagepathhere';` and not any easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for jQuery object.

Try this:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'myimagepathhere';
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery object is not the html element itself. Try with

```
$('<img/>')[0].src = 'myimagepathhere';
```

or

```
$('<img/>').attr('src','myimagepathhere');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing jQuery syntax with "regular javascript" syntax, try:

```
$('img').attr('src', 'myimagepathhere');
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one image, use the image id and not 'img' (you don't want preload all the images in the page)

```
$('#image_id').attr('src', '/Images/xxx.jpg');
```